# Unable to update Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: updates

I'm unable to update Ubuntu 22.04.

`sudo apt-get update`:

```
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease                                            
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease                                                                
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease                                                                 
Ign:5 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                  
Hit:6 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu jammy-infra-security InRelease
Hit:7 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu jammy-infra-updates InRelease           
Err:8 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu jammy Release      
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.52 443]
Reading package lists... Done                              
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: PPA's or *personal package archives* are 3rd party sources that don't support all releases, thus it's on you to check they are well maintained, support your release & not *potentially dangerous* for your release - did you perform any checks?  Any checks of that PPA should have shown it was *abandoned* and thus only supported older releases & is *risky* today.  https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java   (*I got there from the details provided in your question*)

Comment: See also: [Are PPAs safe...](https://askubuntu.com/q/35629)